# How can I get a consistent behaviour for CommonApplicationData folder?

Tags: c#, .net, service, teamcity, profile

I am working on a console application in C# that when run normally will access the common application data folder in "C:\ProgramData" on Vista and Windows 7.

For example:

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

However, there are cases when this application will be spawned from a service (e.g. TeamCity) and this will return something like "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming" rather than "C:\ProgramData". I understand that this is expected behaviour for a service but didn't expect it in my application since it isn't a service (just started by a service).

I would prefer this behaviour to be consistent so that I'm now having duplicated configuration files etc when the application is run manually or by TeamCity. Is this possible?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 0):

How about playing a little with the **Environment Variables**? See [`GetEnvironmentVariable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6k3c7b0) [`SetEnvironmentVariable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes). If your application has enought rights, you won't need to duplicate your configs/code.